# How to convert mysqli code to Oracle code in php?

Tags: php, oracle

I want to setting pagination with data from oracle database in table with specific ROWNUM. At the past, I've done for pagination with mysqli code, and then I want to try pagination with data from oracle database.

This is my myqli code:

```
      $result = $connect2->query($sql10);
        $row5 = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $total_pages = ceil($row5["total"] /     $results_per_page); // calculate total pages with results

        for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  // print links for all pages
        echo "<a href='aog.php?page=".$i."'";
        if ($i==$page)  echo " class='curPage'";
        echo ">".$i."</a> ";
```

So, I want to convert it to pagination data from oracle database.

Can anyone help?